# OpenWrt: prevent that an IP address could be reachable in the network, excluding a few hosts

Tags: openwrt

So there is a network: 192.168.1.0/24. Router is an OpenWrt 12.04 on a WRT160NL.

We got a new network printer. But it's www server is reachable to everyone in the network (and thus everyone can print with it..).

**Q:** How can I disable the network access for all the machines in 192.168.1.0/24 - and only let 2 IP's ex.: 192.168.1.10 and .20 to access the printer? - there isn't ANY access control on the network printer...

Comment: Do you have a firewall?

Comment: the router connects to the ISP, and the clients connect to the router. iptables is on openwrt.

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but I think what you want should be possible if you connect the printer to your router instead of a switch (so that it's only accessible through the router's firewall) and configure `iptables` to drop any traffic whose destination is the printer's IP and whose source isn't one of the two allowed IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you would probably need additional hardware for that.

You need to put the network printer in an independent subnet, connected through a firewall.  If you had VLAN support on the internal switch, you could put the network printer's port on a separate VLAN.  OpenWrt supports VLANs in general, but unfortunately your hardware isn't working correctly at the moment.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt160nl#switch.ports.for.vlans

But if your printer also supports USB, you might use that with the routers USB port.  The recommended solution is [p910nd](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/p910nd.server).  Then you could control access using firewall rules.